# In codeigniter how to get tcpdf custom header and footer

Tags: codeigniter, tcpdf

My controller to generate pdf is as folloe

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class C_test extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("Pdf");    
    }
    public function create_pdf() {
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);    
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Vijay Kumar');
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');   
     set default header data
   $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));

    $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128)); 

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED); 

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);    

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM); 

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);  

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }   
    // set default font subsetting mode
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);   
    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);   
    $pdf->AddPage(); 

    // set text shadow effect
    $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));    

    // Set some content to print
    $html = <<<EOD
    <h1>Welcome to  pdf gen</h1>
EOD;

    // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);  
    $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');    

    }
}
```

pdf.php library

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

class Pdf extends TCPDF
{
 function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 }
}
```

I want to generate a pdf with custom header and footer, header is image and footer is dynamic name and need page number

In controller how to do this to work with custom pdf header and footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need extend TCPDF in order to use custom header and footer

```
class PDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $image_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'logo_example.jpg';
        $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 15, '', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(0, 15, '<< TCPDF Example 003 >>', 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
    }

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}
```

Even I did like this and got my result.

reference: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/

Comment: how can we generate dynamic footer. like I want to display the customer name in pdf.

Comment: You want to display the customer name at footer? or just page number??

Comment: if possible both.

Comment: see, this line print page number in footer

Comment: see, this line print page number in footer: 
$this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

but If you want to print customer name, first you need store customer name in a variable and then using css, as I did, call that variable and print on footer. you need to use css here for in order to print customer name to footer.

Comment: where should i use the variable, please give me example. I'm collecting the data in controller and generating the pdf. The customer name is in a variable like $pdf->Output(strtoupper($applicantname).'_'.strtoupper($applicantid).'.pdf', 'I'); file is generating with the applicant name and id.

Comment: $pdf->Output(strtoupper($applicantname).'_'.strtoupper($appl‌​‌​icantid).'.pdf', 'I'); // pritnts file name with customer name and id, but $applicantname consist the name of the customer, right? if yes, then 
make a div with a class name: and then echo $applicantname ..
 .className{ position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 1rem;  text-align: center; } 
let me know if this work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148996/discussion-between-vijay-kumar-and-sudeep-sagar).